# PHP image upload code not working

Tags: php, file-upload, image-uploading

I have a php image upload code that doesn't upload the image.

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_FILES['file']) && $_FILES['file']['error']==0) {
      $files = $_FILES['file'];
     echo $tmp_name = $files['tmp_name'];
     $moved=move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"../a.jpg");
     if($moved){        
     echo'Done!';
     }
}else{
   echo 'Error uploading, code '.$_FILES['file']['error'];
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="samefile.php">
      <input type="file" name="file">
      <input type="file" name="file">
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

This is the simplified form of my code. In the real scenario there are multiple upload button but only one button can be used at once.

The problem is that it shows the error `Error uploading, code 4`. 
Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Why not use single `<input type="file" name="file[]">`

Comment: It's probably hitting the else. You don't actually echo that string.

Comment: @Saty I could have used that but it doesnt help what i am using the code for.

Comment: @JonStirling Thanks and ya its hitting the else part. But how to fix this?

Comment: Add `echo` to else part and see error code if any. Also add `else` to `move_uploaded_file` and check if error happens there.

Comment: `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE    Value: 4; No file was uploaded.`

Comment: @u_mulder How to fix this?

Comment: Start with __one__ field named `file` on form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113801/discussion-between-sushang-nirola-and-u-mulder).

Comment: @SushangNirola I've answered for you. Try this and let me know if there is any error or anything you don't understand..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, this will work for you to upload multiple files you need to use `name="file[]"` instead of `name="file"` this will submit all the files in array and you can loop each file using for loop in php file..

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="samefile.php">
      <input type="file" name="file[]" >
      <input type="file" name="file[]" >
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

In php file

```
<?php 
if (isset($_FILES['file']))
{
    $total = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
    for($i=0; $i < $total; $i++)// Loop for each file
    { 
      $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
      if ($tmp_name != "")
      {
        $targetFile = "../" . $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
        //Upload the file 
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$targetFile)) 
        {
          echo'Done!';
        }
      }
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: Great ;) glad to help you...  @SushangNirola